# Using \citeauthor in custom bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am using the following bibliography style for my journal article: https://github.com/bopaper/bopaper/blob/master/bmc_article.bst

I want to be able to use `\citeauthor`. If I use is just like that it gives me an error saying `!Undefined control sequence`

If I do `\usepackage{natbib}`, it gives me some more errors;

```
Runaway argument?
]{author2007}
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete
```

How can I use `\citeauthor` for my current bibliography style?

Answer (score 2):

The header of the file `bmc_article.bst` states that it's based on the style file `unsrt.bst`. As such, it's probably meant for numeric rather than author-year (or author-only, in your case!) citation styles. You don't reproduce the errors you say you get if you load the `natbib` package; please read these error messages for potential clues regarding a potential imcompatibility between the `bmc_article` style file and author-year citation styles.

**Addendum** 9/29: The bibtex style file, such as `bmc_article.bst`, defines *both*  the appearance of the citation(s) in the body of the paper -- such as numeric or author-year style -- as well as the appearance of the entries in the bibliography -- e.g., sorted or not, show full first names or only initials, italicization of journal names, etc. If you're not happy with some aspects of the output of the `.bst` file you're working with, you should either choose a different existing `.bst` file or create a new one with the `makebst` utility. To run the latter, just type `latex makebst` at the command line and follow the detailed instructions. One of the questions you'll be asked in the process is whether you want numeric or author-year citations (and some other options): choose "author-year with some modifications". A piece of good news: your newly-created `.bst` file is fully compatible with `natbib` and its `\citeauthor` command. :-)

Comment: I don't understand the LaTeX build errors that well. I have edited my question to add the error that I get.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also post the sentence or two around the point in the input file where the error is being generated?

Comment: `\citeauthor{wassermann2010} have identified......cliffs \cite{wassermann2010}.`

This is one sentence. Another would be;

`...with the presence of such cliffs. \citeauthor{sisay2009} have explained what activity cliffs mean structurally \cite{sisay2009}.`

The dots(...) is just plain text.

Comment: Is it only the \citeauthor command that's causing an error message, or do the other \cite commands do so as well?

Comment: `\cite` also causes error, but only if I do `\usepackage{natbib}`

Comment: That would be because `natbib` redefines `\cite` to behave like `\citet`, which is not going to work with a numerical citation style imposed by the `bmc_article` citation  file. However, if you consult the `natbib` manual, the package is actually perfectly compatible with numerical citation styles, but you will have to give up on using the `\citeauthor` command. :-(

Comment: I have to use `bmc_article.bst`. I don't need `natbib`. Is there some other way to do a `et al.` style citation??

Comment: Look at the output of your `\cite` commands (without loading `natbib`): Is it something like `[1]`, `[2]`, ...? If so, the style is definitely "numeric".

Comment: YEs, the output is `[1]`, `[2]`. Numeric seems to be working. But I want to `Author et al` !!!

Comment: Please see the addendum to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand. I also would like to use \citeauthor with a custom .bst file (provided by a journal). Is the short answer "you can't do this?"