# Use citeauthor with a bibliography style other than plainnat

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am trying to use `\citeauthor` from the `natbib` package with a bibliography style that is provided by a journal. Is this possible? I looked at `plainnat.bst`, but I didn't see any instances of `\citeauthor` that I was hoping to just copy into `mystyle.bst`.

I saw this thread:
[Using \citeauthor in custom bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/using-citeauthor-in-custom-bibliography-style)

but don't understand the solution.

Here are some demo tex/bib files:
http://daviddoria.com/Uploads/Bibtex/

When I use `\bibliographystyle{ieee}`, I get "author undefined" errors on the `\citeauthor` lines. It works fine if I use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

Is it possible to use `\citeauthor` with this IEEE style?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It's always the best to provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no: `natbib` needs specially shaped bibliography styles for being able to extract the authors' names.